# Casting a datatype for a C library in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to work with a C library in c++ which has the function:

```
int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *, MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[], int);
```

From the example C code given, the following is how you would call this library:

```
char filename[] = "filename";
int epochs = 1;
MAGtype_MagneticModel * MagneticModels[1];
if(!MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, &MagneticModels, epochs)) {
    //ERROR
}
```

I attempted to translate this into c++ as follows:

```
char filename[8] = "filename";
int epochs = 1;
MAGtype_MagneticModel * MagneticModels[1];
if(!MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, &MagneticModels, epochs)) {
    //ERROR
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error: C2664: 'int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *,MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[],int)' 
: cannot convert argument 2 from 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[1]' to 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

How would I get c++ to properly reinterpret this for the c library that it is calling?  For reference, the library I am attempting to work with can be found at http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml under the link labeled WMM2015_Windows.zip

Comment: A parameter of type `foo *(*)[]` is equal to `foo ***`. The author likely didn't want to look like a triple star programmer.

Comment: These two pieces of code seem identical apart from the sizing of the character array in the 2nd example

Comment: @Tibrogargan The code is the same.  The difference is that the first piece of code is C code, which compiles in C.  However, the second is trying to run that same code in C++, where it fails.

Comment: @user3830784 Anything valid in C should also run in C++ (with some caveats).

Comment: @user3830784  You're seeing the compilation problem because [1] is not the same as [].  You might want to consider doing something more like `MAGtype_MagneticModel * MagneticModels[] = malloc(sizeof(MAGtype_MagneticModel *));`

Comment: @user3830784 You might also want to change that `char filename[8]` back into `char filename[]`.  If anything ever treats that as a string, you may see some wierd behavior occur

Comment: @Tibrogargan 'MAGtype_MagneticModel * MagneticModels[] = malloc(sizeof(MAGtype_MagneticModel *));' returns 'error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *[]'
There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays'

That being said, I changed 'char filename[8]' back to 'char filename[]', which works locally but can't be declared in the header.

Comment: @user3830784 There's a bunch of things that are going on here that I'd like to have the time to explain, maybe someone else does :).  Try this instead `void *foo =  malloc(sizeof(MAGtype_MagneticModel *));
    MAGtype_MagneticModel (*magnetic_models)[] = (MAGtype_MagneticModel (*)[])foo;`

Comment: Ok, so my g++ compiler is refusing to accept that a pointer to an array of pointers is the same as a pointer to a pointer to a pointer (it really wants to know the size of the array).  There's some switch I should be using to make it stop being pedantic, but I can't remember what it is. (But at least I can reproduce your error, ha ha)

Comment: `filename[8]` is not the same as `filename[]`. It's missing the terminating null character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because an array with a known size ( `type[x]` ) is treated differently by the compiler than an array with an unknown size ( `type[]` ).  One way to avoid this issue is to create an array with an unknown (as far as the compiler is concerned) size to pass into your function:

```
char filename[] = "filename";
int epochs = 1;
void *foo = malloc(sizeof(MAGtype_MagneticModel *));
if (foo) {
    MAGtype_MagneticModel* *magnetic_models = (MAGtype_MagneticModel **)foo;
    if(!MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, (MAGtype_MagneticModel* (*)[]) &magnetic_models, epochs)) {
        //ERROR
    } else {
        // do something with the new magnetic_model;
    }
    free(foo);
}
```

Comment: Attempting to run this code results in the error 'error: C2664: int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *,MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[],int): cannot convert argument 2 from MAGtype_MagneticModel (**)[] to MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast'

Comment: This error shows a different argument type than your original error.  `MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]` vs `MAGtype_MagneticModel *()[]`.  I think you've got formatting issues somewhere.  Please put code in comments in backticks

Comment: Here is the error code properly formatted for comments `error: C2664: 'int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *,MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[],int)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'MAGtype_MagneticModel (**)[]' to 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: Can you show the prototype of the C function you're calling?

Comment: @user3830784 got sick of trying to finesse it and hit it with a hammer